# How can I send and receive data from an Arduino Uno to Arduino Mega using I2C?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, i2c

I am trying to send data as a string from an Arduino Uno to another Arduino Mega. I have read about the I2C connection where we connect the RX to TX oppositely.

How to start and send and receive data between them? I have no idea how the code can be written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At instructables there is a good [post](http://www.instructables.com/id/I2C-between-Arduinos/).

In short the code is

Master code:

```
// Include the required Wire library for I2C
#include <Wire.h>
int x = 0;
void setup() {
  // Start the I2C Bus as Master
  Wire.begin(); 
}
void loop() {
  Wire.beginTransmission(9); // transmit to device #9
  Wire.write(x);              // sends x 
  Wire.endTransmission();    // stop transmitting
  x++; // Increment x
  if (x > 5) x = 0; // `reset x once it gets 6
  delay(500);
}
```

Slave code

```
// Include the required Wire library for I2C
#include <Wire.h>
int LED = 13;
int x = 0;
void setup() {
  // Define the LED pin as Output
  pinMode (LED, OUTPUT);
  // Start the I2C Bus as Slave on address 9
  Wire.begin(9); 
  // Attach a function to trigger when something is received.
  Wire.onReceive(receiveEvent);
}
void receiveEvent(int bytes) {
  x = Wire.read();    // read one character from the I2C
}
void loop() {
  //If value received is 0 blink LED for 200 ms
  if (x == '0') {
    digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
    delay(200);
    digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
    delay(200);
  }
  //If value received is 3 blink LED for 400 ms
  if (x == '3') {
    digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
    delay(400);
    digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
    delay(400);
  }
}
```

In the instructables post a lot more explanation is shown.